# How do I fix Error: std::bad_alloc message when using DPLYR full_join to join 3 large data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, bad-alloc

I have 3 very large files with thousands of observations (file_1 = 6314 rows, file_2 = 11020 rows, file_3 = 2757 rows). I need to join them, so I  used the function `full_join()` from the dplyr package. When I run the code I get this error:`Error: std::bad_alloc` and nothing else.

How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
det = full_join(det1, det2, by = "collectioncode")
det = full_join(det, det3, by = "collectioncode")
```

Comment: Exactly how many rows are in each table? Full joins grow quickly. It sounds like you are running out of memory on your computer.

Comment: det 1 = 6314 rows, det2 = 11020 rows, det3 = 2757. Is it a matter of getting an external drive?

Comment: Try installing the development version of dplyr: `devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")`

Comment: When I try to install that package I get the warning message: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘hadley/dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1).

Comment: Sorry, try this: devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")

Comment: I get the same warning message

Comment: @KristenCyr: maybe try `data.table`? https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/#joinbind-data-sets

Comment: I had the same issue, you can: 1. restructure your joins, 2. try data.table or 3. try dtplyr

Comment: std:bad_alloc is throwed to report failure to allocate memory, volatile memory (RAM). So your full_join is exceeding the free memory of your machine. `data.table` looks like a good try, as @tung said. You can also look if you really need the type of join, or increase your free memory (RAM).

Comment: data.table and dtplyr don't seem to work either. They give me these error messages: Warning message:
In data.table(det1, det2) :
  Item 1 is of size 6314 but maximum size is 11020 (recycled leaving remainder of 4706 items)

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party, but I was running into similar problems with joins that should not have been causing these problems (hence I found this thread). 
Then I noticed that, by default, dplyr's joins match NAs, which blew me dataset into the millions. 
I could fix my issue by setting na_matches to "never", e.g.:

```
det = full_join(det1, det2, by = "collectioncode", na_matches="never")
```

Hope this helps!